# Video stream freezes after few seconds but sound works fine

Tags: video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, android-videoview, freeze, android-mediacodec

I am writing an app to play a m3u8 streaming from the internet using a VideoView. The streaming looks like to play but freezes after few seconds, audio continues working fine despite of this.

If I open the streaming with VLC video player it works fine, so it is not because of the streaming.

The codecs are: (data taken from VLC)

```
Transmission 0
codec: H264 - MPEG4 AVC (part 10) (h264)
Type: video
Video resolution: 720x404
Buffer size: 720x416
Frame rate: 25
Decoded format:    <--VLC shows it blank
Orientation: Top-left
Chrome localisation: left
Transmission 1
Codec: ADTS
Type: audio
Channels: stereo
Sample rate: 44100 hz
bits per sample: 32
```

Find the code below:

**main activity**

```
    package com.name.name;

    import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;

    import android.widget.MediaController;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.widget.VideoView;
    import android.app.Activity;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Cargando vídeo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        VideoView vw = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.myVideoView);

        vw.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        vw.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        vw.setVideoPath("streamingwebaddress.m3u8");
        vw.start();


    }
}
```

**activity main**

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <VideoView
     android:id="@+id/myVideoView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
     android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
     />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.name.name"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.name.name"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}
```

Can somebody please give me a hand with it? It is very weird.
Thanks in advance.

PS: If I change the streaming web address for another m3u8 with Códec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1) it does not start the video (gives an error), if I use an rtsp stereaming address it works fine.